Can a system with a clock slower than the signal sample rate reliably process data using buffering without information loss?
I am trying to understand the limitations of signal processing when the system clock is slower than the incoming signal's sample rate and whether buffering can help mitigate this. Specifically, I have a system (e.g., a CPU) with a clock rate of 1 GHz, and I need to process an incoming signal with a sample rate 4 times higher than the system clock, i.e., 4 GHz.
Given that the incoming signal has a 4 GHz sample rate, it contains frequency components up to 2 GHz (According to Nyquist's theorem, the sample rate must be at least twice the highest frequency component of the signal), which exceeds the system’s clock rate of 1 GHz. This is challenging for real-time processing.
Since computers don't really care about physical things. Instead, they interpret signals as vectors (amplitude) and their corresponding scalar (sample rate), therefore I considered using a buffer to temporarily store the incoming data before processing.
This would imply we can process signal with frequencies above 1 GHz, which corresponds to a signal with a maximum frequency of 2 GHz (4 GHz sample rate signal).
However, since the system clock is much slower than the sample rate of the signal, the finite buffer will eventually overflow as data arrives faster than the system can handle it. Given this scenario, is it reasonable to conclude that no system with a clock frequency slower than the incoming signal's sample rate (e.g., a 1 GHz CPU processing a 2 GHz signal which has 4 GHz sample rate) can reliably process such a signal, even with buffering?
Are there any techniques or architectures that can manage this kind of discrepancy without losing information? Of course, downsampling is definitely losing the information.

As you noticed yourself:

computers don't really care about physical things. Instead, they interpret signals as vectors

right, so all your considerations about 2 GHz signal bandwidth absolutely don't matter at all.
The only question here is: can the computer process 4 billion samples a second, on average.
And there's no general reason it can't. 1 GHz clock rate doesn't mean that it can only process a single sample per such clock rate. For example, any desktop CPU since ca 1996 has had instructions (so-called "SIMD instructions", single instruction, multiple data) that could deal with four numbers at a time (the name of these instruction set extensions were AltiVec on the PowerPC side, and MMX on the x86 side). We're now in a place where modern processors can do 16 floating point (32 bit) multiply-add operations per instruction, with a throughput of 2 instructions per CPU cycle. Go down to 8 bit integers, and you can do 64 additions at a time. So, 4 GS/s: totally doable, on the CPU side of things.
All modern processors have multiple cores, which you could use to either do different processing steps or the same processing steps in parallel on the input data stream. "Computer" for a matter of fact doesn't even imply "CPU", but could just as well be a somewhat programmable special-purpose signal processor, which could have hardware to do much larger computations.
So, yeah, that is possible. Whether or not your specific computer is up to the task of doing your specific signal processing in real-time is a different issue, and does involve the quality of your programming and your compilers. It does raise questions of how you get these samples into your computer (Assuming you have 12 bit samples at 4 GS/s, that's 48 Gb/s, so you're in need of at least 8 lanes of a PCI Express 3.0 link to get this data in – but that's something rather common on (serious) network cards. It does raise questions with what you do with the data afterwards, and it does require you to know very well what you do on the algorithmic and data marshalling side of things to actually make use of the CPU power you have.

Of course it's possible with buffering even with a 1 Hz system clock, but will it eventually buffer overflow? where there is no space for an incoming sample to be stored (since the system clock is a bottleneck still processing earlier samples) during real-time processing, which indicates information loss.

I answered that. "The only question here is: can the computer process 4 billion samples a second, on average." And then the rest of the answer is just "yeah, 4 billion samples per second is something that your computer can do on average". Please make really sure you've understood my answer!

I suspect that MM and the OP are making different assumptions. Maybe the OP wants to do general purpose recursive IIR processing, where the latency for a sample calculation must be less than a system clock cycle. This sort of processing cannot be parallelised as MM is suggesting. This is why we use non-recursive, FIR processing that can be parallelised and take advantage of the parallel facilities in CPUs and FPGAs.

@Neil_UK I don't think so, since recursiveness wasn't mentioned, but buffer overflows were, so single-sample latency constraints aren't of OP's concern, as far as I can tell :) Still an interesting point to comment on; we do parallelize IIRs in high-rate applications occasionally, see for example this presentation. It's a bit of a structure-reshuffle, but it works.

1 GHz clock rate doesn't mean that it can only process a single sample per such clock rate. As far as I understand, it's possible that the processor reads (query) the multiple samples at once (e.g., 8 Giga samples) from buffer and then performs the operation. After processed, it will flush (delete) the processed samples (earlier samples) and then process the next batch of samples (next 8 Giga samples). With this, there is a chance the buffer is empty due to parallel reading. CMIIW.

that sounds right ("deleting" or "flushing" is not how you'd implement a high-throughput buffer though, but that's an implementation detail we don't need to consider here). You're wrong about the CPU handling 8 Gigasamples at once – that makes no sense. Why would you ever make the granularity of operation so big? Do 8 or 16 samples at once. What does "CMIIW" mean?

12 bit samples at 4 GS/s, that's 48 Gb/s. Okay, so it was about data acquisition into buffer. We have bits unit now. In order to prevent buffer overflow, we need an algorithm that can process data above 48 Gbps. Here, since we still have clock system units in GHz (physical unit), we need to convert to logical units (Gbps). Given an arbitrary algorithm and a clock rate, how do we know how many bits are processed per second? CMIIW means Correct Me If I'm Wrong.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What you write in this comment seems rather confused about how computers get data through digital interfaces, and about what an analog to digital converter does.

"All modern processors have multiple cores" --> Billion of processors per year are small embedded ones - doubtful the the majority have multiple cores.  Perhaps better as "All modern desktop processors have multiple cores" or "All these modern processors have multiple cores" to let the reader know you are  talking about the same select ones mentioned above.
